# Dynamically add key/ value and preserve the key in the form it was added

Tags: javascript

I have following code

```
var ids = ["1","2","3"];
var relations = [];
for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
   relations.push({key: 'relation', value: createField(ids[i])});
}
```

where, createField looks like below

```
createField() {
    var field = {details: {name: 'test1', age: 11}};
}
```

At the end of the run, I would like to see output of relations as below:

```
[{'relation': [Object]}, {'relation': [Object]}, {'relation': [Object]}]
```

However, I am getting output like below

```
[[Object], [Object], [Object]]
```

I tried changing code that pushes elements like below too, but no luck

```
relations.push({'relation': createField(ids[i])});
```

Thanks in advance
Ramesh

Comment: `{'relation': [Object]}` is an object, so it will represent as `[Object]`.

Comment: What does it matter what output you get when you print out the array? Isn't the goal for it to be internally correct?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Can you explain it in more detail. And what should be exactly the result?

Comment: Thanks for all your quick comments.

Only when the data is in below format, my server app would be able to accept and persist it
[{'relation': [Object]}, {'relation': [Object]}, {'relation': [Object]}]

I believe the above data structure is valid too in json where every object's key is relation and the corresponding value is a json object

Comment: please specify, how `relations`should look like. please doe not use `[object]` to indicate an object, use `{relation: {details: {name: 'test1', age: 11}}}` if that is what you want.